# Why does LogicalVector to std::vector<double> conversion take so long?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpp11

When using Rcpp to interface with external libraries we must convert from
the Rcpp built-in container classes to, most commonly, standard container
classes. This conversion, as always, has a cost. Typically this overhead
is fairly determinate but in the case of Rcpp's conversion of `LogicalVector`
to a `std::vector<double>` the cost seems out of line with the other type
casting/promotion costs...

Consider the equality of the following six simple conversions from
LogicalVector to std::vector containers...

```
// Equality check functions.
// [[Rcpp::export]]
svi test_auto_conversion_std_int(const svi& v) {
  return v;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
svi test_as_conversion_std_int(const lv& v) {
  svi v2 = as<svi>(v);
  return v2;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
svi test_manual_conversion_std_int(const nv& v) {
  svi v2(v.begin(),v.end());
  return v2;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
svd test_auto_conversion_std_dbl(const svd& v) {
  return v;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
svd test_as_conversion_std_dbl(const lv& v) {
  svd v2 = as<svd>(v);
  return v2;
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
svd test_manual_conversion_std_dbl(const nv& v) {
  svd v2(v.begin(),v.end());
  return v2;
}

    > small_l_vec <- c(T,F,NA)
    > small_i_vec <- as.integer(small_l_vec)
    > small_n_vec <- as.numeric(small_l_vec)
    > all( identical(small_i_vec, test_auto_conversion_std_int(small_l_vec)),
    +      identical(small_i_vec, test_as_conversion_std_int(small_l_vec)),
    +    .... [TRUNCATED] 
    [1] TRUE

    > all( identical(small_n_vec, test_auto_conversion_std_dbl(small_l_vec)),
    +      identical(small_n_vec, test_as_conversion_std_dbl(small_l_vec)),
    +    .... [TRUNCATED] 
    [1] TRUE
```

We get this equality because of Rcpp's templating magic. My template-fu is not
strong enough to dive into why there is such an extreme difference in the overhead
of manually converting vs the automagic conversions as illustrated in these benchmark
results...

```
    > benchmark_as_tested_for_equality()  # includes copy costs
    Unit: microseconds
                                      expr   median neval
         test_as_conversion_std_int(l_vec) 10121.17   500
     test_manual_conversion_std_int(l_vec) 12545.34   500
       test_auto_conversion_std_int(l_vec) 12654.28   500
     test_manual_conversion_std_dbl(l_vec) 18590.10   500
         test_as_conversion_std_dbl(l_vec) 19653.39   500
       test_auto_conversion_std_dbl(l_vec) 26897.93   500  <<< OUCH!
```

Comparing the cost of using the Rcpp containers directly, automatically converted
to std containers of like types, and containers of promoted types like so...

```
# Functions return "size" only so no copy costs.

> declared_direct()      > declared_std_like_types()
          expr median               expr   median
rcpp_lv(l_vec) 1.1280    std_bool(l_vec) 7352.500


> declared_promoted_r()  > declared_promoted_std()
          expr   median            expr     median
rcpp_iv(l_vec) 2932.712  std_int(l_vec)   6790.508
rcpp_nv(l_vec) 5359.769  std_dbl(l_vec)  12810.550 <<< OUCH!
```

... it is easy to see the outlier.  If we attempt to pass the logical vector as a like type std container and then let
c++ do the promotion when construction the new container the results are no better...

```
    > declared_std_like_types_promoted_using_std_promotion()
                            expr    median
     std_bool_promote_int(l_vec) 12725.724
     std_bool_promote_dbl(l_vec) 13626.782
```

**But** if the `LogicalVector` is promoted by Rcpp and *that* is used to populate
a standard container directly the results are much better.

```
 > declared_promoted_r_to_std_like_type()
                            expr   median
  rcpp_lv_promote_std_int(l_vec) 5019.586
  rcpp_lv_promote_std_dbl(l_vec) 8007.522 <<< Much better!
```

What I can't figure out is *why* the automatic conversion from
`LogicalVector` to `std::vector<double>` is so relatively slow...